# Gradio HTML component display mounted on FAST API

Tags: python, fastapi, gradio

I am trying to achieve HTML display message on webpage using gradio mounted on fastapi.

```py
import gradio as gr
from fastapi import FastAPI
from starlette.middleware.sessions import SessionMiddleware
import uuid

app = FastAPI()

def get_user_info(request: gr.Request):
    return  f"<b>Welcome {request.request.session.get('username', 'User')}!<b/>"
    
with gr.Blocks(title="test") as demo:
    gr.Markdown("# Test App")
    with gr.Row():
        with gr.Column():
            user_info = gr.components.HTML(get_user_info)

app = gr.mount_gradio_app(app, demo, "/home")
app.add_middleware(SessionMiddleware, secret_key=uuid.uuid4().hex)
```

The above code is throwing error as `TypeError: get_user_info() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'`

If I write this code again using button click. It will work fine.

```py
import gradio as gr
from fastapi import FastAPI
from starlette.middleware.sessions import SessionMiddleware
import uuid

app = FastAPI()

def get_user_info(request: gr.Request):
    return  f"<b>Welcome {request.request.session.get('username', 'User')}!<b/>"
    
with gr.Blocks(title="test") as demo:
    gr.Markdown("# Test App")
    with gr.Row():
        with gr.Column():
            user_info = gr.components.HTML()
            b2 = gr.Button(value="Logging")
            b2.click(get_user_info, outputs=user_info)

app = gr.mount_gradio_app(app, demo, "/home")
app.add_middleware(SessionMiddleware, secret_key=uuid.uuid4().hex)
```

Output before click

[image]

Output after click

[image]

How can i achieve same using first code and without using button. How to resolve the above error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function has to be called by gradio which only happens if you pass it as callable to a gradio Component, or call it yourself using `get_user_info(request)`.

One way to do it is to use the gradio `Blocks.load` instance method:

```py
import gradio as gr
from fastapi import FastAPI
from starlette.middleware.sessions import SessionMiddleware
import uuid

app = FastAPI()

def get_user_info(request: gr.Request):
    return  f"<b>Welcome {request.request.session.get('username', 'User')}!<b/>"

with gr.Blocks(title="test") as demo:
    gr.Markdown("# Test App")
    with gr.Row():
        with gr.Column():
            user_info = gr.components.HTML()
    demo.load(get_user_info, outputs=user_info)

app = gr.mount_gradio_app(app, demo, "/home")
app.add_middleware(SessionMiddleware, secret_key=uuid.uuid4().hex)

# to launch this example standalone:
# 
# if __name__ == '__main__':
#     import uvicorn
#     uvicorn.run(app, host='127.0.0.1', port=8007)
```